# How to divert the SonataAdminBundle for both admin and manager

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I would like to know the basic idea guideline.

I am managing entity by SonataAdminBundle for now and get used to it.
I would like to make progress step forward.

I want to make both admin and user edit the entity by sonataadminbundle

**[For example]**

I have table/entity like this.

```
Id |User  | data
1  |bear  | sarmon
2  |dog   | meat
3  |monkey| banana
4  |bear  | peanuts
5  |dog   | corn
```

Of course I(admin) can edit entity from admin_dashboard of SonataAdminBundle.

However I want to let user 'bear' edit only 1 and 4 rows.

If I make edit/update/list script from the scratch in Controller.
It is easy to accomplish.

However, I think it is like useless work because  SonataAdminBundle has better UI than I make from scratch.

So, Does anyone know the appropriate way for this kind of ideas??
or it is bad idea to use SonataAdminBundle for both user and admin??

---

I want let user bear see only bear related tables like.

```
Id |User  | data
1  |bear  | sarmon
4  |bear  | peanuts
```

At first I am struggling with
`public function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)`
however this code is only called one time.
I can't find the right answer.

So I guess I need to put this kind of code somewhere else.

```
if ($user == bear){
array_push($table,$line);
}
else {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's completely fine to use the AdminBundle for an user and a privileged-user at the same time.
You can easily ask the Admin if the current logged in user has been granted to edit the rows 1 or 4.

For example you could use:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $mapper)
{
    /* either identify your custom rows here or via ACL/ROLES */
    if (!$this->isGranted('EDIT')) {
      // not allowed
    }
}
```

For security concerns (and depending on your use-case), please note that this won't prevent your non-privileged users to show/list those entities (since the above example only overrides the form/edit mask). Of course, you can add you logic to those methods too.

Depending on your security-handler, you can use everything that's supported by symfony (Roles, ACL, ...).
Please take a look on how to configure it to your needs here: https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/3-x/doc/reference/security.html

Comment: Thank you for giving me basic thought and assured. I will implement step by step!!

Comment: I have read that document. but It is a little bit what I wanted to do. I addedthe article . Could you give some help if possible??

Comment: Thanks to you, I think I can simplify my problem, I will make another thread.